How to speed up "Run until failure" function in Visual Studio Tests Explorer?
I have test that failed one time and I want to catch this failure once again. When I start test mannualy I have to wait until test to run will be determined and other ctivities, so one test run takes about 3 seconds. When i start multiple tests, only first test takes si much time, others complete in obout 100 ms. When using "Run until failure" feature i expect that the test will be run quickly, but it takes 2-4 seconds for every run. Is there a way to configure this behaviour?
So i just tried "Run until failure"(Ctrl + R, U) and it takes more time then i want for every run
I don't like the idea of creating test where i will just call my test 1000 times, because i need to empty test database every time (i do it test suite constructor)

Do you roughly remeber what error that was? Or at least What kind of error?

Its error on asserts, i remember what was it about, but i have no proof because i can't catch it anymore

Can you add the assertion expression to the question? Maybe it is flakey in itself?

It's just checking bool variable to be true, nothing special, device.Connected.Should().Be(true);
Right now i just wondering about run until failure feature, for future cases

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If individual tests have no dependencies that prevent them from being run in any order, turn on parallel test execution in the settings menu of the toolbar. This can noticeably reduce the time taken to run all the tests.
